# auto populate slug field working when I create a name with admin site, but not working when I create a name with a form... any idea why?

Tags: html, django-models, django-forms

[Error it's showing] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhRwh.png

auto populate slug field working when I create a name with admin site, but not working when I create a name with a form... any idea why this is happening?

## Category Model

```
    from django.db import models


    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128, primary_key=True, unique=True)
        likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        slug = models.SlugField(default="", null=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from rango.models import Category


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ('name',)}

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from rango.models import Category, Page


class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the category name.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)
```

## views.py

The url maps to this view.

```
def add_category(request):
    form = CategoryForm()

    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST)

        # if Form is Valid
        if form.is_valid():
            # save category to database
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            print(forms.errors)
    return render(request, 'rango/add_category.html', {'form': form})
```

This is the first page user sees. They add a category and click Submit Button.

## Add_category.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Category Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <h1>Add a Category</h1>
    <form id="category_form" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field }}<br/>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Category"/>
    </form>
    <a href="/">Back to Home</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```